# SkobblerFrameWork not getting exact locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, skmaps

In skobbler framwork  Not gettig exact location,

In Google API if we given an Address likes

```
"107, Floor 1,Civic Centre 2,Earl Street,Coventry,CV1 5RR "
```

we will get exact location but, in skobbler not getting exact location, gets all near by locations.

Is there any possible way to get the exact point.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if the SDK supports one line search, the answer is no for the moment. Each address category (city, street, number) are treat as a different field.

If you're asking how to show an exact address on the map (geocoding), this is the class that you have to use: [SKMultiStepSearchSettings](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.2.0/Classes/SKMultiStepSearchSettings.html)  and for the hierarchy level of the search use the street.

But take into consideration that in OSM some street numbers are missing and in that case the middle of the street will be shown.